# Silverlight Toolkit - Accordion - Styling the Header

Tags: silverlight

I am using the Accordion in the Silverlight toolkit.

I want to style the Accoridon item header (I don't like the default baby blue). But I can't seem to figure it out. Blend won't let me load it up either. Can someone show some sample code of an Accordion Item with just a basic green background?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately as with many controls both Toolkit and otherwise there often many different places where color is used other than simply Foreground and Background.  These colors are "hardcoded" into the Templates of the controls.  This requires that you supply a new template to the control in order to modify these colors.

You need fo clone the existing `AccordianButton` template, either using Blend if you have it or you'll find in the source code here

> Silverlight3\Source\Controls.Layout.Toolkit\Accordion\AccordionButton.xaml

So you basically have in your application a resource dictionary containing this style:-

```
<Style x:Key="MyAccordionButtonStyle" TargetType="layoutPrimitivesToolkit:AccordionButton">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate TargetType="layoutPrimitivesToolkit:AccordionButton">
          <!-- Adjusted Clone of template here -->
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
 </Style>
```

The parts of the template you would want to tweak are the two `Border` element named "ExpandedBackground" and "MouseOverBackground".   These have hardcoded Background values that you will want to modify.  You may also want to look at the `Stroke` property on the "FocusVisualElement" Rectangle.

Comment: For SL 4:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Silverlight\v4.0\Toolkit\Apr10\Source\Source code\Controls.Layout.Toolkit\Accordion

Comment: I copied the whole Style code in my resource dictionary and set the following property to Accordion:  AccordionButtonStyle="{StaticResource AccordionButtonStyle}". But, it crashes. Can you please suggest would could be possible problem? Also, is it possible to just copy part of the AccordionButton.xaml file in resource directory, which i want to override. Actually, i am trying to understand how the overriding concept works.